# I am unable to get the Json object in response from the web service

Tags: android, android-volley

The we service i am using is takes string values and the response is a json object. When i click on the button after entering the values i get an error `com.android.volley.server` error. I checked the server on postman it's working fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    // json object response url
    private String urlJsonObj = "http://walletuncle.com/myservice.asmx/UserLogin/";

    // json array response url
    private String urlJsonArry = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_array.json";

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnMakeObjectRequest, btnMakeArrayRequest;

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private TextView txtResponse;

    private EditText editusername;
    private EditText editpassword;


    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserId";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";


    private String jsonresponse;

    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnMakeObjectRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);
            // btnMakeArrayRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnArrayRequest);
            txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

            editusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
            editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);



            btnMakeObjectRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // making json object request
                    makeJsonObjectRequest();
                    }
                    });


        }

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

        final String username = editusername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editpassword.getText().toString().trim();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlJsonObj,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {



                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d("Data added", "Data done");

                }

                },


                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                })
        {
            @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                    params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);



                    return params;
                }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);




        showpDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                String name = response.getString("Name");
                //String email = response.getString("email");
                //JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("phone");
                //String home = phone.getString("home");
                //String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                jsonResponse = "";
                jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                //jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                //jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                //jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n";

                txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // hide the progress dialog
                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                });

        //Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);


    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use [ksoap2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242) library.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: i just posted the webservice in postman without userid and password and saw html coding. now my question is the way i have sent the user id and password is it correct?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In this webservice if i send two strings and the response will be a json object. i changed some code and now the parsing of json data is done but i am not able to post the two strings. can anyone help?